# Removing file extension in PHP, whilst also creating a link

Tags: php, file, substr

I have this code which is taking the name of files in a directory and then creating a link to those files. However, the text in the link has the file extension on the end. I want to remove this but at the same time keep the correct link to the file i.e. the HTML link needs the extension to remain on it - like this:

```
<a href="/documents/other/file.pdf">File</a>
```

So here is my script:

```
$linkdir="documents/other";
$dir=opendir("documents/other");

$files=array();

while (($file=readdir($dir)) !== false)
{
   if ($file != "." and $file != ".." and $file != "index.php")
   { 
    array_push($files, $file);
   }
}

natcasesort($files);
$files=array_reverse($files);

foreach ($files as $file)
print "<li><a href='/$linkdir/$file' rel='external'>$file</a></li>";
```

Here is the code I need to integrate to remove the file extension:

```
  $name = substr($file, 0, strrpos($file, '.'));
```

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put if you allready have the code.. what is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you mean that you want this?

```
foreach ($files as $file){
    $name = substr($file, 0, strrpos($file, '.'));
    print "<li><a href='/$linkdir/$file' rel='external'>$name</a></li>";
}
```

I can't find any other question in your post :)

Comment: Yes! Exactly like that - I'm sure I tried that but it didn't work LOL. Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe you didn't add the openstache / closestache?

Answer (score 1):

Using `pathinfo()` is a more robust solution, in case some files have name with more dots (like `someclass.inc.php`):

```
$parts = pathinfo($file);
$name  = $parts['basename'];
```